# imagemagick djvu delegate missing

Tags: .net, imagemagick, djvu

I was hoping to read djvu files through imagemagick..
I installed imagemagick for windows and then checked the delegates using

convert -list configure

I cannot see the djvu delegate in the list.
I uninstalled imagemagick and then installed djvulibre and then reinstalled imagemagick.

Still no luck, cannot see the djvu delegate.

Ideas?

Prasad

Answer (score 1):

DJVU is missing because it uses the GPLv2 license. We cannot link with this library because we release the binary version of ImageMagick under the Apache license.

You will have to download, build and link the sources from here: http://djvu.sourceforge.net/

**Warning:** If you use DJVU in your program it has to be released under GPL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like djvu is disabled by default. You can check by opening the [magick-config.h](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/magick/magick-config.h?rev=2823#L56) file. Run `validate` from the command line to test.

```
validate
```

In that case, you have to build from source.

**References**

- [ImageMagick: Advanced Windows Source Installation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#windows)
- [magick-config.h File Reference](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/magick-config_8h.html)
- [ImageMagick: Supported Image Formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported)
- [build multiple jars from a single project source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559753/1113772)